# Password protect PDF using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, pdf-generation, jspdf

Is there a way to password protect PDF document while generation using any JS library? Something like-

```
doc = new jsPDF({'password':'lethal'});
var initialx = 10;
var initialy = 25;
var end = 190;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check library you use for method like setProtection or something else like in this library [here](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_016.phps). There are a lot of parameters You have to check but I am sure you'll handle it :)